# Find the date in a dataframe that is closest to another dataframe of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of stock data that looks like the following, where Date and Ticker are indexes.

| Date | Ticker | Close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-20 | NVDA | 99 |
| 2021-01-19 | AAPL | 100 |
| 2022-01-19 | MSFT | 110 |
| 2023-01-20 | AAPL | 101 |
| 2023-01-20 | MSFT | 111 |

I have a separate dataframe of data that looks like the following, where Date and Ticker are indexes.

| Ticker | Date | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2023-01-10 | data |
| AAPL | 2022-11-19 | data |
| MSFT | 2022-06-17 | data |
| MSFT | 2021-01-25 | data |
| NVDA | 2019-12-01 | data |
| NVDA | 2019-08-19 | data |
| NVDA | 2019-01-22 | data |

I want to create a date column in the first df that is the closest date in the second df with the same stock ticker symbol.

So the output df would look like the following:

| Date | Ticker | Close | Closest_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03-20 | NVDA | 99 | 2019-12-01 |
| 2021-01-19 | AAPL | 100 | 2022-11-19 |
| 2022-01-19 | MSFT | 110 | 2022-06-17 |
| 2023-01-20 | AAPL | 101 | 2023-01-10 |
| 2023-01-20 | MSFT | 111 | 2022-06-17 |

I'm not sure how to do this in a pythonic way that doesn't include a lot of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

out = pd.merge_asof(
    # save index and sort Dates
    df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='Date'),
    # sort Dates and rename column
    df2.sort_values(by='Date').rename(columns={'Date': 'Closest_Date'}),
    left_on='Date', right_on='Closest_Date',
    by='Ticker', direction='nearest'
).set_index('index').loc[df1.index] # restore original order
```

*NB. the code to restore the original order is required if the initial dates are sorted per ticker. If `df1` is already sorted by date, you can simplify to:*

```
out = pd.merge_asof(
    df1,
    df2.sort_values(by='Date').rename(columns={'Date': 'Closest_Date'}),
    left_on='Date', right_on='Closest_Date',
    by='Ticker', direction='nearest'
)
```

Output:

```
        Date Ticker  Close Closest_Date  Data
0 2020-03-20   NVDA     99   2019-12-01  data
1 2021-01-19   AAPL    100   2022-11-19  data
2 2022-01-19   MSFT    110   2022-06-17  data
3 2023-01-20   AAPL    101   2023-01-10  data
4 2023-01-20   MSFT    111   2022-06-17  data
```